# Importing each Excel cell into it's own text box in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, import, microsoft-excel

I have multiple text cells on an Excel sheet and I want each of them to be placed on a separate text box in InDesign and autoflow.

I created a text box on each page of the Master Page because I want to have a text box on each page.
Now I go to the first page, I go to File - Place - select my file - hold Shift and click on the text box. All is good the text autoflow and creates pages for all the text I have, my problem is that in one text box I have the text from multiple cells, I only want that one cell to fit into one text box.

I thought that the import options will let me choose to break that but I don't see any setting to help:

[image]

Comment: An Excel file will be inserted as a *table* in a *story* which flows through several *text frames*. So you want to only show one cell of the table on each page. That's not necessarily bad, but not the way tables are normally used. Does this have to be dynamic? If not you could just copy/paste the content of all cells to InDesign and do some quick *Find/Change* to turn it into paragraphs with *frame breaks*. (I would need to see an example of the data to tell you exactly how.)

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem at the end. I converted the table into text with tabs and paragraphs and did your mentioned part of  Find/Change to turn it into paragraphs with frame breaks.